# Pystacia can't find MagickWand on OS X

Tags: python, macos, imagemagick

For some odd reason Pystacia is not able to find MagickWand.h on OS X.

I tried to tweak $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH and $C_INCLUDE_PATH but no luck.

I have imagemagick up and running.

```
$ mdfind MagickWand.h 
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.010/share/doc/ImageMagick/www/api/MagickWand/struct__MagickWand.html
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.0-10/include/ImageMagick/wand/MagickWand.h
```

And keep getting this error:

```
>>> import pystacia
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pystacia/__init__.py", line 193, in <module>
init()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pystacia/__init__.py", line 28, in init
raise TinyException('Could not find or load magickWand')
pystacia.util.TinyException: Could not find or load magickWand
```

I went further down to figure it out how pystacia looks for MagickWand.h:

```
from ctypes.util import find_library
resolved_path = find_library('MagickWand')
if not resolved_path:
    raise PystaciaException('Could not find or load magickWand')
```

Still no lucky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking to the latest [pystacia](https://bitbucket.org/liquibits/pystacia) code from bitbucket I realized that the version from pip is pretty old (from 2011) and a installation from the latest code solved my problem -- as I can afford to run unreleased code.

I also entered an Issue on bitbucket so the maintainer put out a new code release.